# What does (sol) in a chemical equation mean?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solutions, notation

I'm reading Shrivers Inorganic Chemistry book and some of the equations have a (sol) state on them. I'm sure the book has already defined this but I cannot find where.
Examples:

\begin{align}
  \ce{[NH3OH]Cl (sol) + NaOBu &-> NH2OH (sol) + NaCl (s) + BuOH (l)}\\
  \ce{SbF5 (l) + HF (l) &-> H2F+ (sol) + SbF6- (sol)}
\end{align}

Comment: It is a non-standard form of writing solution, IUPAC suggets (sln) https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4165/what-is-the-standard-way-to-denote-physical-states-in-a-chemical-reaction

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The state (sol) or (solv.) stands for "solvated". Since you are dissolving $\ce{HF}$ in liquid $\ce{SbF5}$, there is no water in that system (which would cause hydrolysis). So it is not correct to use (aq), since it is a **nonaqueous system**.

Here are some other examples:

- Autoprotolysis of liquid ammonia:
  $$\ce{2NH3 (l) <=> NH4+ (sol) + NH2- (sol)}$$
- Autoprotolysis of nitrosyl chloride:
  $$\ce{NOCl (l) <=>  NO+ (sol) + Cl- (sol)}$$
- Dissolving sodium metal in liquid ammonia creates [solvated electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvated_electron):
  $$\ce{Na (s) <=>  Na+ (sol) + e- (sol)}$$

Comment: I have updated your post with chemistry markup. If you want to know more, please have a look [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) and [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945). You may also have a look at my meta answer to '[What is the standard way to denote physical states in a chemical reaction?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4166/4945)' and resources linked within. The IUPAC actually suggests (sln).